# re-trigger the same tab index event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i am using Jquery UI tabs , to trigger show event i use following statement
    $tabs.tabs('select',1);
after this code executes a tab is set to #tabs-1 but i am failed to re trigger the same event on same tab when #tabs-1 is already shown. so how to re-trigger the same tab event.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are loading the tab content via ajax.  If so you can use the [load method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-load) to reload or load any tab.

```
$tabs.tabs('load',1);
```

Comment: No I am not using load method to load a tab

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already figured this out or got the solution from some other post. I am posting an answer that works for me.

In jquery-ui-1.8.21.js

```
if (( $li.hasClass( "ui-tabs-selected" ) && !o.collapsible) || 
    $li.hasClass( "ui-state-disabled" ) || $li.hasClass( "ui-state-processing" ) ||
    self.panels.filter( ":animated" ).length || 
    self._trigger( "select", null, self._ui( this, $show[ 0 ] ) ) === false ) {
        this.blur();
        return false;
}
```

When a tab is selected the first two conditions

```
( $li.hasClass( "ui-tabs-selected" ) && !o.collapsible)
```

hold true so if you omit them, on clicking a selected tab again it wont return false, thus calling select on a selected tab again.

P.S - I have not yet seen any disadvantages because of this, so you might do some extra checks to see it doesn't break anything.