# How to force 'select' event in jQuery Tabs if tab already selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

The main issue is that if tab is already selected the 'select' event doesn't fire if i set the same tab id again. The reason i required in this to update the content located in the tab.
I need a way to fire 'select' even if i specify already selected tab id.

In theory this should work
Something like:

```
tabControl.tabs('select', -1);
tabControl.tabs('select', selectedTab);
```

but 'select' takes zero based index, so it doesn't reset tabs as desired and doesn't raise event again.

Any solution?

Comment: May be you already got a solution for this, if not please check my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935238/re-trigger-the-same-tab-index-event/12343648#12343648

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend selecting tab twice just because you need to reload its contents. Instead I solved same issue by calling the tabs() 'load' method instead of 'select'.

```
var selectedTab = tabControl.tabs('option', 'selected');
tabControl.tabs('load', selectedTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the selected tab object (selectedTab), try to call the event directly with something like:

```
selectedTab.select();
```

Comment: i have no selected tab object. Tabs plugin doesn't expose any similar properties

Comment: I had similar problem and I found the below works.

$('#tabName').bind('click', function() {  }); 
$('#tabName').trigger('click');